# Web scraping from multiple pages with for loop part 2

Tags: python, html, for-loop, web-scraping

My original problem:

"I have created web scraping tool for picking data from listed houses.

I have problem when it comes to changing page. I did make for loop to go from 1 to some number.

Problem is this: In this web pages last "page" can be different all the time. Now it is 70, but tomorrow it can be 68 or 72. And if I but range for example to (1-74) it will print last page many times, because if you go over the maximum the page always loads the last."

Then I got help from Ricco D who wrote code that it will know when to stop:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

url='https://www.etuovi.com/myytavat-asunnot/oulu?haku=M1582971026&sivu=1000'
page=requests.get(url)
soup = bs(page.content,'html.parser')

last_page = None
pages = []

buttons=soup.find_all('button', class_= "Pagination__button__3H2wX")
for button in buttons:
    pages.append(button.text)

print(pages)
```

This works just fine.

Butt when I try to combine this with my original code, which also works by itself I run into error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Käyttäjä/PycharmProjects/Etuoviscaper/etuovi.py", line 29, in <module>
    containers = page_soup.find("div", {"class": "ListPage__cardContainer__39dKQ"})
  File "C:\Users\Käyttäjä\PycharmProjects\Etuoviscaper\venv\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 2173, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(
AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'find'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?
```

This is the error I get.

Any ideas how to get this work? Thanks

```
import bs4
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
import re
import requests

my_url = 'https://www.etuovi.com/myytavat-asunnot/oulu?haku=M1582971026&sivu=1'

filename = "asunnot.csv"
f = open(filename, "w")
headers = "Neliöt; Hinta; Osoite; Kaupunginosa; Kaupunki; Huoneistoselitelmä; Rakennusvuosi\n"
f.write(headers)

page = requests.get(my_url)
soup = soup(page.content, 'html.parser')

pages = []
buttons = soup.findAll("button", {"class": "Pagination__button__3H2wX"})
for button in buttons:
    pages.append(button.text)


last_page = int(pages[-1])

for sivu in range(1, last_page):

    req = requests.get(my_url + str(sivu))
    page_soup = soup(req.text, "html.parser")
    containers = page_soup.findAll("div", {"class": "ListPage__cardContainer__39dKQ"})

    for container in containers:
        size_list = container.find("div", {"class": "flexboxgrid__col-xs__26GXk flexboxgrid__col-md-4__2DYW-"}).text
        size_number = re.findall("\d+\,*\d+", size_list)
        size = ''.join(size_number)  # Asunnon koko neliöinä

        prize_line = container.find("div", {"class": "flexboxgrid__col-xs-5__1-5sb flexboxgrid__col-md-4__2DYW-"}).text
        prize_number_list = re.findall("\d+\d+", prize_line)
        prize = ''.join(prize_number_list[:2])  # Asunnon hinta

        address_city = container.h4.text

        address_list = address_city.split(', ')[0:1]
        address = ' '.join(address_list)  # osoite

        city_part = address_city.split(', ')[-2]  # kaupunginosa

        city = address_city.split(', ')[-1]  # kaupunki

        type_org = container.h5.text
        type = type_org.replace("|", "").replace(",", "").replace(".", "")  # asuntotyyppi

        year_list = container.find("div", {"class": "flexboxgrid__col-xs-3__3Kf8r flexboxgrid__col-md-4__2DYW-"}).text
        year_number = re.findall("\d+", year_list)
        year = ' '.join(year_number)

        print("pinta-ala: " + size)
        print("hinta: " + prize)
        print("osoite: " + address)
        print("kaupunginosa: " + city_part)
        print("kaupunki: " + city)
        print("huoneistoselittelmä: " + type)
        print("rakennusvuosi: " + year)

        f.write(size + ";" + prize + ";" + address + ";" + city_part + ";" + city + ";" + type + ";" + year + "\n")

f.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main problem has to do with the way you use `soup`. You first import `BeautifulSoup as soup` - and then you override this name, when you create your first BeautifulSoup-instance:

`soup = soup(page.content, 'html.parser')`

From this point on `soup` will no longer be the name library `BeautifulSoup`, but the object you just created. Hence, when you some lines further down try to create a new instance (`page_soup = soup(req.text, "html.parser")`) this fails as `soup` no longer refers to `BeautifulSoup`.

So the best thing would be importing the library correctly like so: `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup` (or import AND use it as `bs` - like Ricco D did), and then change the two instantiating lines like so:

`soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser') # this is Python2.7-syntax btw`

and

`page_soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, "html.parser") # this is Python3-syntax btw`

If you're on Python3, the proper `requests`-syntax would by `page.text` and not `page.content` as `.content` returns `bytes` in Python3, which is not what you want (as BeautifulSoup needs a `str`). If you're on Python2.7 you should probably change `req.text` to `req.content`.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Finding your element with `class name` doesn't seem to be the best idea..because of this. Same class name for all the next elements.

[image: Same class name for multiple divs]

I don't know what you are looking for exactly because of the language. I suggest..you go to the website>press f12>press ctrl+f>type the `xpath`..See what elements you get.If you don't know about `xpaths` read this. https://blog.scrapinghub.com/2016/10/27/an-introduction-to-xpath-with-examples